# Obtaining frequency content of time sequence

Tags: spectral-analysis

I have a long sequence of time values (instants in time where events happened) and I would like to detect perodicities in this data.  It's possible to sample these points onto a gigantic grid and take an FFT, but the times are known very accurately relative to the grid spacing available even for a 10M+ point FFT. So doing this entails a bunch of interpolating onto a coarse grid.

Are there other techniques to extract spectral/periodicity information?

I thought Lomb-Scargle could be used, but once I dug into it I realized that LS is geared toward getting a regular spectrum of unevenly sampled data. I have no amplitude data, just times, so if I put all ones for the amplitudes, it just gives me a flat spectrum back.  I want the underlying assumption to be that the time signal is all zero except for impulses at the specified times.